# Mysql Connector C++ data retrieval question

Tags: mysql

So, the result of a query is stored in a ResultSet. And that type has multiple methods for data retrieval such as getString, getInt etc.

I'm curious how the data is stored in that object. Is all the data stored as a string, and then converted to the required type, according to the function called(getInt would convert it to an int for example).

OR the data is already stored as the actual type, and if that is so, is it ok if I call getString on a value that is supposed to be an int? Will the conversion take place without problems?

Comment: Y don't you try it by yourself and share the results with us?